# Angular Testing: provide injected @Attribute in TestBed

Tags: angular, testing, dependency-injection

I have a component that gets an attribute injected via `@Attribute`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html'
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Attribute('foo') private foo: string) {
    // do something with foo
  }
}
```

Now I would like to write a test using Jasmine and Karma. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to provide this attribute in the test via the `TestBed` injector.

This is what I tried:

```
describe('FooComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: 'foo', useValue: 'bar'},
        {provide: Attribute('foo'), useValue: 'bar'},
      ],
      declarations: [FooComponent],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should merge outer class', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // do actual testing
  });
});
```

After some research I also defined the following but without success:

```
Inject('foo')(FooComponent, null, 0);
Attribute('foo')(FooComponent, null, 0);
```

The parameter passed to the constructor is always `null`. Does anybody know a solution? I'm using Angular 5.2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Also struggling to provide an `@Attribute()` decorator override.

As a work around you can either change the `@Attribute()` in the constructor to an `@Input() foo: string;` on the component class. Or use a wrapper component, and set the attribute on the wrapper component as shown below:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Attribute, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe('FooComponent', () => {
  it('should allow you to use attribute decorator', () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooComponent, WrapperComponent],
    });

    const wrapperFixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperComponent);
    wrapperFixture.detectChanges();

    const fooComponent = wrapperFixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(FooComponent)).componentInstance;
    expect(fooComponent.bar).toEqual('baz');
  });
});

@Component({
  selector: "foo-component",
  template: "<p>Foo works: {{bar}}</p>",
})
class FooComponent {
  bar: '';
  constructor(@Attribute('foo') private foo: string) {
    this.bar = foo;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "wrapper-component",
  template: "<foo-component foo='baz'></foo-component>"
})
class WrapperComponent {
}
```

I think using `@Input()` on the component is going to work better for me. I cannot see any downside so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the wrapper component for testing. At least I'm able to write a test with this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use `@Input` as I want to read the provided classes on the host element's `class` attribute and store them internally. Then these classes are merged with a dynamic set of additional classes that reflect additional information about the internal state and the merged set of classes is exposed via `@HostBinding('class')` which overrides the entire class attribute.